# Subdomain of custom domain on Github pages

Tags: github, dns, subdomain, cname, github-pages

We are allowed to use our own custom domain with Github Pages.

For example, I have my page: http://example.com which points to http://username.github.io/project

But now I need to create a subdomain for another folder inside my repo. like

http://zuckerberg.example.com ---> which points to ---> http://username.github.io/project/zuckerberg

Is it possible to accomplish on github? I can't find any documentation about subdomain of custom domains :/

I found this so far https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages but it's really confusing

Comment: How did you get a custom domain for a project?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not be able to point a custom subdomain to http://username.github.io/project/zuckerberg.
You will have to point it to another project http://username.github.io/otherproject
Some more documentation https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site.

Answer (score 1):

*Examble of real-world CNAME files*

**The username.github.io repository has a CNAME file with the domain www.domain.com.**

```
 - The User Pages site at username.github.io redirects to www.domain.com.
 - The Project Pages site at username.github.io/project redirects to www.domain.org/project.
```