# Set custom domain for user and project pages

Tags: github-pages

I would like do something like:

- mydomain.tld (apex) redirect on www (user page)
- www.mydomain.tld (www custom) on user page
- myproject1.mydomain.tld (custom) on project page

Actually I've a DNS zone like:

```
@ 10800 IN A 192.30.252.153
@ 10800 IN A 192.30.252.154
www 1800 IN CNAME user.github.io.
```

But, I don't know how to add a custom domain for project pages, because I can't do a `CNAME` on `user.github.io/myproject1`...

In Github, I've set:

- user.github.io repo: www.mydomain.tld
- myproject1 repo: myproject1.mydomain.tld

Actually it works for www.mydomain.tld, I think it's okay for mydomain.tld too (just wait propagation). But I don't know how to do for projects pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subdomain of custom domain on Github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479210/subdomain-of-custom-domain-on-github-pages)

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but he says what I want is possible, but I don't find how to to that in the Gihub Pages doc :-/ Because, they says to use CNAME everywhere. :-(

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is _not_ possible (we wanted to do the same thing last year and couldn't find a way, I spent hours trying to figure it out) and that's what the answer says: not possible.

Comment: What you _can_ do is add a completely different domain. Apparently the redirect support that drives github pages will only differentiate at the `mydomain.tld` level and basically doesn't care about the third-level domain. But if you find a way, please post an answer to your own question!

Comment: Yes, I tries 2 things. If it works, I post an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Github:

- Define the domain you want to use:

  - In user.github.io repository, define the: www.mydomain.tld
  - In projects repository, define: project.mydomain.tld

In the DNS zone file:

```
@ 1800 IN A 192.30.252.153
@ 1800 IN A 192.30.252.154
project 1800 IN CNAME user.github.io.
www 1800 IN CNAME user.github.io.
```

In the configuration, we use `CNAME` to define subdomains, and the `A` on IPs: 192.30.252.153 and 192.30.252.154 to define the apex.

Then:

- www.mydomain.tld serve the user.github.io pages
- mydomain.tld redirect on www.mydomain.tld (alias)
- project.mydomain.tld serve the user.github.io/project pages

Because apex is define, we also can do:

```
project 1800 IN CNAME @
```