# How can I create my own subdomain of my github.io page?

Tags: html, github, url, subdomain

Not sure if this belongs here, but: 
I have a github pages site, norway-yv.github.io. I want to create e.g. the subdomain of that subdomain short.norway-yv.github.io for URL-shortening (like, creating short.norway-yv.github.io/trains for my train-information repository project). How can I create the short.norway-yv.github.io subdomain using github pages?

Comment: By the way: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479210/subdomain-of-custom-domain-on-github-pages or similar ones, I want to create subdomain of the .github.io subdomain, not of a custom domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t.

Github offer you *username.github.io* for your main site and *username.github.io/project-name* for projects.